# Is it a normal thing to write app data in Android using file API instead of room database in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, file, android-room

From Android database it seems there are following ways of storing app data in a file(permanent instead of memory storage):

1. Room database
2. Shared preferences
3. File stream

Shared preferences is just for small key value pair and not for app data.

YouTube and Google seem to suggest room database is the best option for app data management. The problem though is that most of it is either in jetpack or older version of room database with Kotlin. When I try to use newer version of Android SDK with kotlin then it just keeps crashing with endless errors to the point of giving it up.

Is writing by stream file API for app data a normal thing?
The app data is JSON text data.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific

Comment: "When I try to use newer version of Android SDK with kotlin then it just keeps crashing with endless errors to the point of giving it up." -- while I have not used it much recently, I am rather confident that Room works. "Is writing by stream file API for app data a normal thing?" -- I do not know what you consider "normal" to be, but storing images, videos, JSON blobs, and the like in files seems fairly commonplace. SQLite (using Room, SQLDelight, etc.) is great for relational data, but not everything fits the relational structure well.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The documentation and tutorials for Room on the Android web site are completely up to date. Jetpack is the name of all of Android’s official, current libraries. Whether a database is best or even applicable depends on what kind of data you need to store.

Comment: It's JSON text type data.

Comment: Then saving the JSON as a file seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Can you write this as a comment with any useful information so that I can mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal to use any way to store data. But for specific reasons some of approaches may be more preferable.

Problems with files is that you should be prepared to handle different errors. For example if user cleared cache of app, file became corrupted or outdated. Also you must check if file exists before reading it and after every change rewrite new data to it.

Room helps to achieve same result using less boilerplate code. It should work with new Android SDK, so maybe we can help if you show us error (for example there is common problem when you change your Entity class without deleting old database. In this case removing user's data of app can help)

If your app data isn't big you also can make it serializable (or simply convert to string) and store in SharedPreferences